# Problems using svn merge --reintegrate (subversion 1.6.17)

Tags: svn, svnserve, mod-dav-svn

I'm trying to use the Subversion merge --reintegrate feature to merge a development branch back to the project trunk. Subversion version 1.6.17 on Fedora 14.

I get the following

`[me@fedora14 product_trunk]$ svn merge --reintegrate ^/product/branches/NewFeature
svn: Retrieval of mergeinfo unsupported by 'svn://fedorabox/e2458/branches/ErrtsFeaturDev'`

I've checked versions of svnserve and svn client. These are both 1.6.17 -which should support the reintegrate feature.

`[root]# svnserve --version
svnserve, version 1.6.17 (r1128011)
   compiled Jun  2 2011, 15:24:04
...
[root]# svn --version
svn, version 1.6.17 (r1128011)
   compiled Jun  2 2011, 15:24:04`

I've also checked the dates on apache svn modules (am I using apache with svn:// ?) The dates check out .

`[me@fedora14 modules]$ ls -l *svn*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  13520 Jun  3  2011 mod_authz_svn.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 155328 Jun  3  2011 mod_dav_svn.so`

This Fedora 14 machine has been updated from an earlier version of Fedora, so our Subversion repository was most likely initially created with a pre-1.5 Subversion. I think this could be my problem, but I can't find anything indicating what if anything needs to be changed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow-up to bahrep:

your server and client may be rather fresh versions, but it's also "format of repository", changed over time (and rleases)… and new versions of tools are backward-compatible with old formats. Check value from `db/format`file (on FS of repository, not file in repo), it have to be less than "Format 3", which is minimal requirements of merge-tracking.
And yes, `svn upgrade` repository

Comment: Thanks Bahrep and Lazy Badger. The db/formatfile indicates it is version 2. Looks like this is my problem. svnadmin upgrade looks like the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the server or the repository format is old and does not support `svn:mergeinfo`. Therefore, your merge behavior should correspond to SVN 1.4 or older (see [SVNBook 1.4](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/)).

Note that `svn:mergeinfo` was introduced in SVN 1.5.0 (released on 19 June 2008). It definitely makes sense to upgrade your SVN client and server to the latest version 1.10.x and run the [`svnadmin upgrade`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.upgrade.html) command to upgrade the format of your repositories.

Generally speaking, you are now missing all the new features and improvements introduced in SVN after ~2008 year.

Comment: Hi Bahrep. Like it says in the post, the svn version is 1.6.17. the problem was that the database format 
 wasn't updated when svn was updated, so that database file format (db/formatfile) is still 2. As you mentioned, svnadmin upgrade looks like what I need.